# How to implement Debounce analog for ngxs action?

Tags: typescript, debouncing, ngxs

I have search input:

```
<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="projectFilter()">
```

When user is typing It will call projectFilter function after every model change.

How can I implement Debounce with ngxs?

for example dispatch actions only after 0.5 sec after user finish typing?

```
  projectFilter() {
      this.store.dispatch([
        new SomeAction()
      );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create an observable chain using a `BehaviorSubject`  that dispatches the action with `debounceTime()`.

```
// somewhere in your component class
projectFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('')

projectFilter() {
  // set next value instead of dispatching
  this.projectFilter$.next('current value')
}

ngOnInit() {
    // debounce whenever a new value is available with debounce
    this.projectFilter$.pipe(
      debounceTime(1000),
      tap(() => {
        this.store.dispatch(new MyAction())
      })
    ).subscribe()
}
```

Note: Code not tested. Just use it to understand the concept & implement accordingly.

Alternatively, you might want to use reactive forms. With that, you get things like `valueChanges` as an observable for free.

Hope this helps.